# How to use two parameters for the same column in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I tried to find a similar question on Stack overflow without success...

Here is my Stored Procedure code:

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME]
  @IN_dtmin datetime, 
  @IN_dtmax datetime = null, 
  @IN_key varchar(500), 
  @IN_set varchar(80), 
  @IN_locktype varchar(500)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodeSet' THEN  VALUE END) AS CodeSet,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'KeySet' THEN  VALUE END) AS KeySet
FROM LOCKREGISTER LR LEFT JOIN 
     LOCKTYPES T
     ON LR.IDLOCKTYPE = T.IDLOCKTYPE LEFT JOIN 
     PRODUCTATTRIBUTES PA
     ON LR.IDPRODUCT = PA.IDPRODUCT AND 
        PRODUCTATTRIBUTE IN ('CodeSet','KeySet')
WHERE LR.DT BETWEEN IIF(@IN_DTMIN IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMIN) AND IIF(@IN_DTMAX IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMAX)
  AND (PA.VALUE like ISNULL(@IN_key,'%') OR (PA.VALUE IS NULL AND @IN_key IS NULL)) 
  AND (PA.VALUE like ISNULL(@IN_set,'%') OR (PA.VALUE IS NULL AND @IN_set IS NULL))
  AND (T.LOCKTYPE like ISNULL(@IN_locktype,'%') OR (T.LOCKTYPE IS NULL AND @IN_locktype IS NULL))
GROUP BY IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE;
END
```

This is the result if I don't apply any filters:

[image]

And this is the result if I execute the Stored Procedure with the `dates filter` and the `Set` filter:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, in the CodeSet column the results become 'NULL'.

How can I keep the values ​​of the CodeSet column when executing the SP? (Some of the filters might be null in some case).

This would be an example of the desired result for the first line:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the fact that `PRODUCTATTRIBUTES` is an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) table, which are notoriously hard to deal with in queries.

Note that in the second execution of the query, which includes the parameters, the value you entered for `@IN_set` shows up in the `KeySet` column because you're not distinguishing between `PRODUCTATTRIBUTE` values (`CodeSet` vs `KeySet`) in your `WHERE` clause.

In order to simplify the logic in queries like this, I typically join to the EAV table repeatedly, creating sub-queries that only contain the key/value pairs I need for each attribute. So, in this case, I would join to `PRODUCTATTRIBUTES` twice, once to retrieve the `CodeSet` values of interest, then again to get the `KeySet` values. I would also shift the aggregation to those sub-queries, which eliminates ambiguity and also reduces the amount of data being pulled into memory.

This is untested, for lack of tables and data to test against, of course, but an educated guess at the new structure would look something like this.

```
SELECT IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE,
       CS.CodeSet,
       KS.KeySet
FROM LOCKREGISTER LR LEFT JOIN 
     LOCKTYPES T
     ON LR.IDLOCKTYPE = T.IDLOCKTYPE LEFT JOIN 
     ( -- Sub-query to get 'CodeSet' values by IDPRODUCT
      SELECT 
        IDPRODUCT,
        MAX(VALUE) AS CodeSet
      FROM PRODUCTATTRIBUTES
      WHERE PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodeSet'
      GROUP BY IDPRODUCT
     ) AS CS
     ON LR.IDPRODUCT = CS.IDPRODUCT LEFT JOIN
     (  -- Sub-query to get 'KeySet' values by IDPRODUCT
      SELECT 
        IDPRODUCT,
        MAX(VALUE) AS KeySet
      FROM PRODUCTATTRIBUTES
      WHERE PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'KeySet'
      GROUP BY IDPRODUCT
     ) AS KS
     ON LR.IDPRODUCT = KS.IDPRODUCT

WHERE LR.DT BETWEEN IIF(@IN_DTMIN IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMIN) AND IIF(@IN_DTMAX IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMAX)
  AND (KS.KeySet like ISNULL(@IN_key,'%') OR (KS.KeySet IS NULL AND @IN_key IS NULL)) 
  AND (CS.CodeSet like ISNULL(@IN_set,'%') OR (CS.CodeSet IS NULL AND @IN_set IS NULL))
  AND (T.LOCKTYPE like ISNULL(@IN_locktype,'%') OR (T.LOCKTYPE IS NULL AND @IN_locktype IS NULL));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks Eric for your time and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

What ever I have understood from your code is, You merely need a ISNULL function. So upgrade your SELECT query to -

```
SELECT IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodeSet' THEN  VALUE END), @IN_set) AS CodeSet,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'KeySet' THEN  VALUE END), @IN_set) AS KeySet
FROM LOCKREGISTER LR LEFT JOIN 
     LOCKTYPES T
     ON LR.IDLOCKTYPE = T.IDLOCKTYPE LEFT JOIN 
     PRODUCTATTRIBUTES PA
     ON LR.IDPRODUCT = PA.IDPRODUCT AND 
        PRODUCTATTRIBUTE IN ('CodeSet','KeySet')
WHERE LR.DT BETWEEN IIF(@IN_DTMIN IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMIN) AND IIF(@IN_DTMAX IS NULL,GETDATE(),@IN_DTMAX)
  AND (PA.VALUE like ISNULL(@IN_key,'%') OR (PA.VALUE IS NULL AND @IN_key IS NULL)) 
  AND (PA.VALUE like ISNULL(@IN_set,'%') OR (PA.VALUE IS NULL AND @IN_set IS NULL))
  AND (T.LOCKTYPE like ISNULL(@IN_locktype,'%') OR (T.LOCKTYPE IS NULL AND @IN_locktype IS NULL))
GROUP BY IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE;
```